Updating value with next value in same column in Snowflake
I have a view which looks like this.



Device ID
Date
Op Cost




A
5/1/23
100


A
5/2/23
125


A
5/3/23
130



Problem: for a given Device_ID and increasing date, if Op Cost is greater than the previous value, then create a new column called Status and make the second value as P. Then update the 1st value of Status as 'P'.
Expected output:



Device ID
Date
Op Cost
Status
RN




A
5/1/23
100
P
1


A
5/2/23
125
P
2


A
5/3/23
130
I
3



With LAG function, I am checking whether the second value of Op Cost is greater or not. Then for 2nd row, with a Case statement, made value of Status as P. However, I am not sure how to make 1st value of Status as P.
I cannot update a CTE in Snowflake using Update and Set statement. Also, since this view will hit production, I cannot create a intermediate view and Update/Set that same view in prod.
Code snippet:
SELECT
    Device_ID, 
    Date,
    Op_Cost,
    LAG (Op_Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Device_ID ORDER BY Date ASC) AS Lag_Op_Cost,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Device_ID ORDER BY Date ASC) AS RN,
    CASE 
        WHEN Lag_Op_Cost - Op_Cost > 0 
            THEN 'P' 
            ELSE 'I' 
    END AS Status
FROM
    Device_Details;

What do I need to do to update the first value of Status as P, grouped by Device_ID and Date?

Your expected output does not seem to agree with your stated rules.

I cannot update a CTE in Snowflake using Update and Set statement. Here's how to update from the result of a CTE: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008Y627ESAR/update-when-using-cte

Can you help us reproduce a table with the data? Do you want to update that table, or do you want to update the view? How would you update the view, without updating the table with the data?

There will be one view, not table. Hence the view column in the view needs to be updated.
